# Form Input Not Accepting Spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I've got a form using JavaScript that sends a user to a different page depending on their input using "if/else" statements. However, the input field will not accept spaces. It will accept every character except spaces. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this.

EDIT: I have added the HTML for the entire form, including the submit button.

EDIT 2: I have also updated my JS to reflect the 'switch' statements, rather than else if, as recommended by Mister Jojo.

EDIT 3: Just to clarify, if I past spaces in, it will work. But if I just type them it will not show a space.

Below is the HTML, CSS, and JS that goes along with the input form.

```
<!-- This is the HTML for the entire form -->

    <<form onSubmit="return checkAnswer();">
                                              <input class="nice-select wide" placeholder="Enter Your State" id="state" type="text" maxlength="55" class="box" autofocus />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--<p>You have to pay: <span>$0</span></p>-->
                            <div class="submit_btn">
                                <button class="boxed-btn3" value="SUBMIT" type="submit">Continue</button>
                            </div>
                          </form>
```

```
<!-- This is the script that is in the head of the document controlling the redirect. -->

    <script>
    function checkAnswer(){
      var response = document.getElementById('state').value;

      if (response == "Kentucky")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "kentucky")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "KY")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "ky")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "New York")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "new york")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "NY")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "ny")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "Washington")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "Washington St")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "Washington ST")
        location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "Washington st")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "washington")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "washington state")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "Washington State")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "Washington state")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "washington State")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "wa")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else if (response == "WA")
      location = 'https://linxdalton.com'; // 'right.html';

      else
      location = 'https://google.com'; // 'wrong.html';
      return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Below is all of the CSS that is associated with the input element.

```
.nice-select::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  width: 5px;
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  color: #ddd;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 16px;
  right: 25px;
  color: #AAB1B7;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}


-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: -internal-light-dark-color(black, white);
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark-color(white, black);
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 11px system-ui;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: blue;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #e8e8e8;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
}


    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #7A838B;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
```

That's all the code connected with that input element. Let me know if you can find any reason that it wouldn't be accepting spaces!

Thanks!

Comment: where is `</form>` ? (end tag)

Comment: your css is wrong

Comment: The `onSubmit` attribute should just be `checkAnswers()` without the return. Also, what do you mean by not "accepting spaces"? Could you please provide more details as to what happens when you put spaces in the text box. Thanks.

Comment: @LuketheGeek I mean that the text box will not accept space as a character.

Comment: @MisterJojo It is below the submit button. I've edited the post to include the entire form for clarification.

Comment: perhaps your keyboard space key is simply faulty. you should try your code with a different keyboard or PC

Answer (score 1):

better to code  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

```
 function checkAnswer(){
  let response = document.getElementById('state').value;

  switch (response) {
    case 'Kentucky':
    case 'kentucky':
    case 'KY':
    case 'ky':
    case 'New York':
    case 'new york':
    case 'NY':
    case 'ny':
    case 'Washington':
    case 'Washington St':
    case 'Washington ST':
    case 'Washington st':
    case 'washington':
    case 'washington state':
    case 'Washington State':
    case 'Washington state':
    case 'washington State':
    case 'wa':
    case 'WA':
    location = 'xyz.com'; // 'right.html';
      break;

    default:location = 'https://google.com'; // 'wrong.html';
      break;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented this into my code and it is definitely a lot cleaner. However, I'm still not sure why the input is not accepting spaces as a character.

Comment: @BenSmith normally it should, but it is impossible here to understand what you could have done to have this problem, the code that you provide does not reveal anything of this kind

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it! It was a script that I had linked to the page that was affecting spaces, I'm not completely sure what the contents of the script were that affected spaces, but nonetheless the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to same problem on Angular project, due to following script

```
fromEvent(window, 'keydown')
  .subscribe((event: any) => {
  if ([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Since space keycode is 32 , it is prevent to typing space in all input.
Delete this script or replace **window** with a **nativeElement** to apply script on specific component.